# ios 5 shows white font on textView

Tags: ios, colors, textview

I have a textView, in an ipad app, im using the following,

```
self.textView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 73, 665, 85)] autorelease];
self.textView.delegate = self;
[self.textView setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

[self.textView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f]];
//[self.textView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:153/255.0 green:153/255.0 blue:153/255.0 alpha:1]]; //color
//self.textView.textColor =[UIColor grayColor];
[self addSubview:self.textView];
```

it shows the right font color on ios 4, but on ios5 the font goes WHITE???

why?

ios4
[image]

ios5
[image]

how to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: I actually had a similar problem and I would do it differently. Did you try not giving any color at all? Are there any background colors? If yes, can you remove them and see what's being displayed?

Also, I would change [self addSubview:self.textView] as [self.view addSubview:self.textView];

Comment: hi , thank you, i have tried with out setting any color at all, with same result, ios4 fine, ios 5 white font, thanks. pd, self.view is not recognized,

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing in the code you provided that would indicate the textView turing text White. There must be some other method you are not including that is setting this text white. I would do a search for **`white`** throughout your project to see if the color is getting set somewhere else. Also, I would check Interface Builder to see if theres any indication of the text being changed to White.

Comment: hi, thanks, i have looked for white, and theres is no white being attributed to my text, also Im not using Interface builder, and the other strange thing is that the text shows fine in ios4 but white in ios5??, thanks

Comment: I've tried setting a textViews text to blue (exactly as you have), and the text is blue, latest iOS 5 SDK. BTW, can you post a screen of the textView with some (white) text in it?

Comment: have you tried setting another color, or comment out the color portion of the code?

Comment: yes man, commented out so black default [ios4], and different properties for color as in code above, what could it be?, cheers